# Is there any equivalent to ORACLE SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'OS_USER') in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I know it's weird to ask this question, but I'm looking for a way to get the `OS USER` in `MySQL`; not the schema user or the device name.

For instance; in `oracle`, you can get the `OS USER` using:

```
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'OS_USER') FROM DUAL;
-- it returns n.awad for example
```

In `MYSQL` I found these statements, but none of them returns the required value:

```
SELECT USER(); 
-- it returns schemaUser@deviceName
SELECT CURRENT_USER();
-- it returns schemaUser@%
SELECT HOST FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE State ='executing';
-- it returns deviceName:port
```

So, is there any function that returns the required value?

Comment: Are you aware that this information is provided by the client application in Oracle and can not be relied upon?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name really? but I used it in a trigger and I got the required information.

Comment: You can't rely on that information - especially not for security reasons. The JDBC or ODBC driver and the Oracle client stuff simply provide a default value for the OS user but nothing prevents the application using those client software to provide a different name (the same is true fot application name as well). So if you rely on that in your trigger for security reasons, you don't have any security at all