# How to extract used table from SelectConditionStep<Record>

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I'm extending on my [last question I asked about jOOQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67399212/how-to-map-to-an-existing-hibernate-model-using-jooq-fetchinto). In the Hibernate models the `@Filter` annotation gets used, and I want to apply this same 'default filter' to the jOOQ queries. As I'm passing a jOOQ query to the `nativeQuery(org.jooq.Query query, Class<E> type)` I was wondering if it's possible to extract the table (`TableImpl<?,?>`) used from the `FROM` clause in the jOOQ query (`org.jooq.Query`).

This is what I've tried:

```java
private static <E> SelectConditionStep<Record> applyDefaultFilters(Class<E> type, SelectConditionStep<Record> query)
    {
      if (BaseOrganizationModel.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
        query
            .getQuery()
            .addConditions(
                query
                    .getQuery()
                    .asTable()
                    .field("organization_id", Long.class)
                    .eq(currentOrganization().id));
        if (SoftDeletableModel.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
          query
              .getQuery()
              .addConditions(query.getQuery().asTable().field("deleted", Boolean.class).eq(false));
        }
      }
      return query;
    }
```

The result is this SQL, which is not what I want. I want it to filter the corresponding table.

```sql
select distinct `EventGroup`.*
from `EventGroup`
where (
  ...
  and `alias_100341773`.`organization_id` = ?
  and `alias_17045196`.`deleted` = ?
)
```

I want this

```sql
select distinct `EventGroup`.*
from `EventGroup`
where (
  ...
  and `EventGroup`.`organization_id` = ?
  and `EventGroup`.`deleted` = ?
)
```

Is this possible at all? And if not, what possible other routes are there? (aside from the obvious passing the table to the function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using jOOQ 3.16 query object model API

jOOQ 3.16 introduced a [new, experimental (as of 3.16) query object model API, which can be traversed](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/model-api/).

On any `Select`, just call [`Select.$from()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Select.html#$from()) to access an unmodifiable view of the contained table list.

#### An alternative, dynamic SQL approach for the ad-hoc case

Every time you're trying to mutate an existing query, ask yourself, is there a more elegant way to do this using [a more functional, immutable approach do dynamic SQL](https://blog.jooq.org/a-functional-programming-approach-to-dynamic-sql-with-jooq/)? Rather than appending your additional predicates to the query, why not produce predicates from a function?

```java
private static Condition defaultFilters(Class<?> type, Table<?> table) {
    Condition result = noCondition();

    if (BaseOrganizationModel.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
        result = result.and(table.field("organization_id", Long.class)
                                 .eq(currentOrganization().id));

        if (SoftDeletableModel.class.isAssignableFrom(type))
            result = result.and(not(table.field("deleted", Boolean.class)))
    }

    return result;
}
```

And now, when you construct your query, you can add the filters:

```java
ctx.select(T.A, T.B)
   .from(T)
   .where(T.X.eq(1))
   .and(defaultFilters(myType, T))
   .fetch();
```

#### A generic way to transform your SQL

If you really want to mutate your query (e.g. in a utility for all queries), then a transformation approach might be better suited. There are different ways to approach this.

**Using views**

Some RDBMS can access session variables in views. In Oracle, you'd be setting some `SYS_CONTEXT` variable to your `organization_id` inside of a view, and then query only the (possibly updatable) views instead of the tables directly. MySQL unfortunately can't do the equivalent thing, see [Is there any equivalent to ORACLE SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'OS_USER') in MYSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65993205/521799)

[I've described this approach here in this blog post](https://blog.jooq.org/be-careful-when-emulating-parameterised-views-with-sys_context-in-oracle/). The advantage of this approach is that you will never forget to set the predicate (you can validate your view source code with CI/CD tests), and if you ever forget to set the session context variable, the view will just not return any data, so it's quite a secure approach.

Together with the `WITH CHECK OPTION` clause, you can even prevent insertions into wrong `organization_id`, which improves security.

**Using a `VisitListener` in jOOQ**

This is the most powerful approach to do this in jOOQ, and exactly what you want, but also quite a tricky one to get right for all edge cases. [See this post about implementing row level security in jOOQ](https://blog.jooq.org/implementing-client-side-row-level-security-with-jooq/). Starting from jOOQ 3.16, there will be better ways to transform your SQL via https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12425.

Note, it won't work for plain SQL templates that do not use any jOOQ query parts, nor for JDBC based queries or other queries that you may have in your system, so be careful with this approach as you might leak data from other organisations.

Of course, you could implement this step also on the JDBC layer, using jOOQ's [`ParsingConnection` or `ParsingDataSource`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/parsing-connection/), that way you can intercept also third party SQL and append your predicates.

This can work for all DML statements, including `UPDATE`, `DELETE`. It's a bit harder for `INSERT`, as you'd have to transform `INSERT .. VALUES` into `INSERT .. SELECT`, or throw an exception if someone wants to insert into the wrong `organization_id`.

**Using a `ExecuteListener` in jOOQ**

A bit more hackish than the above `VisitListener` approach, but generally easier to get right, just regex-replace the `WHERE` clause of all your statements by `WHERE organization_id = ... AND` in an `ExecuteListener`.

To play it safe, you could reject all queries without a `WHERE` clause, or do some additional trickery to add the `WHERE` clause at the right place in case there isn't already one.

**Using jOOQ's equivalent of Hibernate's `@Filter`**

jOOQ's equivalent of Hibernate's `@Filter` is the [`Table.where(Condition)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Table.html#where(org.jooq.Condition)) clause. It's not an exact equivalent, you'd have to prevent direct access to `T` in your code base and make sure users access `T` only via a method that replaces `T` by `T.where(defaultFilters(myType, T))` instead.

This approach currently loses type safety of the `T` table, see: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8012

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I think I want to kinda obfuscate the filters, so other developers (including myself!) don't have to think about the `organization_id` and `deleted` columns on almost all the models. It creates extra work that is not necessary if the filters get appended to a function they use anyway.

Comment: The functional approach is more elegant from a broad perspective. I guess I wanted to try something more funky as a way to approach this problem of the default `@Filter` in the Hibernate models. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Bram: Yes, that's what I thought - thus the second section. I'll expand a bit on it, since this is your main interest here.